# Oracle SQL where clause evaluating two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have basic SQL skills but I'm stumped by this:

```
create table scores 
(
    name varchar2(15), 
    history_grade varchar2(1), 
    math_grade varchar2(1)
);
```

```sql
insert into scores (name, history_grade, math_grade) values ('Bill', 'A', 'A');
insert into scores (name, history_grade, math_grade) values ('Sue', 'F', 'F');
insert into scores (name, history_grade, math_grade) values ('Mary', 'C', 'B');
insert into scores (name, history_grade, math_grade) values ('Austin', 'C', 'A');
insert into scores (name, history_grade, math_grade) values ('Kyle', 'B', 'B');
```

I want to query rows where either `history_grade` and `math_grade` are *both* not 'A' OR both not 'F'. If either history_grade or math_grade are 'A' or 'F' but the other is not an 'A' or 'F' then I still want the row.

I'm trying this:

```
select * 
from scores 
where (history_grade <> 'A' and math_grade <> 'A')
  and (history_grade <> 'F' and math_grade <> 'F' )
```

but this only returns Mary and Kyle. I need Mary, Kyle and Austin in the result set since Austin has only one A but not two A's.

I hope this makes sense, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   scores 
WHERE  (history_grade, math_grade) NOT IN (('A', 'A'), ('F', 'F'))
```

or you can use `AND` and `NOT`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   scores 
WHERE  NOT ( history_grade = 'A' AND math_grade = 'A' )
AND    NOT ( history_grade = 'F' AND math_grade = 'F' )
```

or:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   scores 
WHERE  ( history_grade <> 'A' OR math_grade <> 'A' )
AND    ( history_grade <> 'F' OR math_grade <> 'F' );
```

Which all output:

| NAME | HISTORY_GRADE | MATH_GRADE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | C | B |
| Austin | C | A |
| Kyle | B | B |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dIaEfm5t)

Answer (score 2):

may be something like this -

```
select * from scores where 
CONCAT( history_grade, math_grade ) not in('AA','FF')
```

Comment: Well done, Kostyra. I like your answer. :)

Comment: A nice idea, but such usage of functions in a `WHERE` clause often slow down the query.